# Weblogic EJB error "Commit can be issued only when there are no requests awaiting responses"

Tags: weblogic, ejb-3.0

Working with EJB 3.0 and WebLogic and getting an error that's driving me insane!!

I have a stateless local session bean that conform to the following interface

```
@Local
public interface ReportRequestManager {
   void addRequest(ReportRequest rr) ;
   List<ReportRequest> getAllRequests();
   String getCEPingResult();
   String getPEPingResult();
}
```

ReportRequest is an entity bean and the first two methods just persist and retrieve the requests, and works perfectly when call from my servlet.

The last two methods makes call to another EJB server (an ECM, IBM FileNet), it simply use the provided API to ping the ECM's engine over EJB.  And this is where the error below occurs when call from a servlet.  What does even this mean?

To make things more bazaar, everything works just fine on a local install of WebLogic (10.3.4), however, when deployed to a server running WebLogic (10.3.3), it failed.

Any guesses?

> Servlet failed with Exception
>   javax.ejb.TransactionRolledbackLocalException: Error committing transaction:; nested exception is: javax.transaction.SystemException: Commit can be issued only when there are no requests awaiting responses. Currently there is one such request
>       at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.EJBRuntimeUtils.throwTransactionRolledbackLocal(EJBRuntimeUtils.java:232)
>       at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.EJBRuntimeUtils.throwEJBException(EJBRuntimeUtils.java:130)
>       at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.BaseLocalObject.postInvoke1(BaseLocalObject.java:626)
>       at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.BaseLocalObject.__WL_postInvokeTxRetry(BaseLocalObject.java:427)
>       at gov.sandia.tl.rr.logic.ReportRequestManagerBean_425hac_ReportRequestManagerImpl.getRequestWorkInbox(ReportRequestManagerBean_425hac_ReportRequestManagerImpl.java:138)

Comment: In your weblogic-ejb-jar.xml file, have you set up clustering for your bean? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/ejb/DDreference-ejb-jar.html#wp1116050 Like:

<stateless-clustering>
<stateless-bean-is-clusterable>True</stateless-bean-is-clusterable>
<stateless-bean-load-algorithm>random</stateless-bean-load-algorithm>
</stateless-clustering>

Comment: I really thought that was it, but just tried it and didn't work, and also found out that it wasn't clustered.